# How to install League Of Legends?

Tags: 12.04, games

I've been trying to install the League of Legends few days ago and the results have not been good. I installed the game properly and everything but when I start the game the screen goes black, only the names of champions and menus appear in red. Will my video card work, or just can not play it in Ubuntu?

Comment: On how to install lol, follow this: [League of Legends under Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu) All bug related issues should be asked on the lol Pol page [League Of Legends - Supported software - PlayOnLinux - Run your Windows applications on Linux easily!](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html)

Answer (score 0):

These are the latest instructions from the [WineHQ AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19141&iTestingId=84444), they are for 14.04 (Trusty), but the same should work on 12.04 (Precise). What you need to do is build a custom patched version of a specific `wine` version. Here is how to do it (also works for x86 without chroot):

First, install the `schroot` and `debootstrap` packages:

```
sudo apt-get install schroot debootstrap
```

Now create a configuration file for `schroot`:

```
sudo editor /etc/schroot/chroot.d/trusty_i386.conf
```

Put this in the new file:

```
[trusty_i386]
description=Ubuntu Trusty
personality=linux32
directory=/srv/chroot/trusty_i386
root-users=your_user_name
type=directory
users=your_user_name
```

Create a working installation of Ubuntu inside the chroot. You can replace http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ with an appropriate mirror from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors:

```
sudo mkdir -p /srv/chroot/trusty_i386
sudo debootstrap --variant=buildd --arch=i386 trusty /srv/chroot/trusty_i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

Make `apt-get` work from within the chroot. Gen and paste `sources.list`. Don't forget to add wine PPA.  http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/index.php:

```
sudo editor /srv/chroot/trusty_i386/etc/apt/sources.list
```

Enter the chroot:

```
sudo schroot -c trusty_i386 -u root
```

Get the basic packages:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6E80C6B7
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F9CB8DB0
apt-get update
apt-get install ubuntu-minimal
apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Install the build dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep wine
```

Getting source and patching `wine`:

```
apt-get install wget
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/wine/wine-1.7.23.tar.bz2
tar -xvf wine*
cd wine-*

wget http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=xSNJjkMY -O patch.diff
patch -p1 < patch.diff
```

Building Deb pack (-jN where N number of CPU cores)

```
make -j4 depend && make -j4
```

Exit chroot and install. To be able to use Wine from outside the chroot, Wine's dependencies must be installed outside the chroot. The easiest way is to exit the chroot and install a prepackaged copy of Wine:

```
logout
cd wine-*
sudo apt-get install wine 
sudo make install
```

Install winetrics:

```
winetricks wininet vcrun2005 corefonts adobeair d3dx9
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm assuming your hardware is up to the task, but as far as I know League of Legends doesn't have a native Linux port, so it's running in wine. Games in wine can work but can also be a tricky business in my experience. 
I found this tutorial online: http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=973373 you should give it a try. Otherwise I really don't know and you might just be out of luck.